# Laravel mix.js inside a loop doesn't output anything

Tags: javascript, laravel, webpack, laravel-mix

I am working on a Laravel/VueJs project, and I am trying to compile my js files with the Laravel mix API.

Until now, it was working perfectly, I was just chaining my assets, like this :

```
mix.js('path/to/asset/index.js', 'public/js/apps/my_asset.js')
    .js('path/to/asset_2/index.js', 'public/js/apps/my_asset_2.js')
    .js('path/to/asset_3/index.js', 'public/js/apps/my_asset_3.js')
    ...
```

But this solution is not satisfying as I got more and more files to add to the list. So I decided to automate this process.

What I want to do is read the content of a directory and find all the .js files I want to compile. Then I loop through this array and run `mix.js()` on each file. My code looks like this :

```
const readdir = require('readdir-enhanced');    
readdir('resources/assets/js/modules/', {deep: 2}, (err, files) => {
    files.map(file => {
        if (file.match(/index\.js$/)) {
            const moduleName = file.replace('/index.js', '');
            mix.js(`resources/assets/js/modules/${file}`, `public/js/${env}/apps/${moduleName}_app.js`)
        }
    });
});
```

The problem is that `mix.js()` does not work, there is no output file generated.

When I `console.log()` inside the loop, it works, so I am certain that I go inside the loop. I also checked the values of the variables `file`, `env` and `moduleName`, and they are correct (so the problem does not come from my paths).

I guess `mix.js()` cannot run inside a loop, does anyone have encoutered this issue already? And have you figured out a solution?

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: This has nothing to do with loops. The async callback is probably the problem.

Answer (score 1):

Indeed it was a problem with the async callback, I did not read the doc of readdir-enhanced carefully.
To solve the problem, I just used the synchronous function to read the directory:

```
let files = readdir.readdirSync('resources/assets/js/modules/', {deep: 2});
files.map(file => {
    if (file.match(/index\.js$/)) {
        const moduleName = file.replace('/index.js', '');
        mix.js(`resources/assets/js/modules/${file}`, `public/js/${env}/apps/${moduleName}_app.js`);
    }
});
```

Thank you tkaus! for pointing me in the right direction :)